# Make IF statement case sensitive.

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, case-sensitive

I am working on a vb forms project. In a part of my project I need to protect it by a password. I want to compare the TextBox's Text to a string. I need to compare the cases of the strings too.

```
 if TextBox1.Text = "Password" then
     MsgBox ("Succes")
 Else
     MsgBox ("Wrong Password")
 End if
```

But i want to make it case sensitive. Such that, it should just pass when i enter "Password".

Thank you.

Comment: While a correct answer has already been given, I would strongly like to recommend you don't store the password in plain text, but instead you should store a salted hash of the password! Please see here https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: This is already case sensitive. Are you looking for case insensitive comparison instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should already do a case sensitive comparison, unless you've overridden the default bevaviour using `Option Compare Text` in your source code, or via *Project / Properties / Option Compare*.

To explicitly make it case sensitive, use `String.Compare` with `false` as the value for `ignoreCase`:

```
If String.Compare(TextBox1.Text, "Password", false) = 0 then
    MsgBox ("Success")
...
```

See the documentation for [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: But that makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

By default the code you have already should be case sensitive. But you can specify the type of comparison to do explicitly by using `String.Equals` with the `comparisionType` overload. For example:

```
if TextBox1.Text.Equals("Password", StringComparison.Ordinal) then
     MsgBox ("Succes")
Else
     MsgBox ("Wrong Password")
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already case sensitive. When you compare a string, in this case "Password" is not equal to "password" since the comparison is based on the ascii value, "P" has a lower ascii code value than "p".